# What (if anything) do I gain by mirroring partitions on the same USB drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, redundancy

I have a small amount (a few dozen items of a few kilobytes each) of essential data to store, which I will need to access over the coming **decades**. While the data is highly confidential, its value to others is debatable, and my budget is small.

I recently purchased a bunch of brand-name 8 GB USB flash drives to store this data. I'm wondering: does creating two partitions on each drive and storing the same data on each actually get me anything? I'm thinking it might buy me some redundancy if some of the flash becomes corrupt, but wouldn't save me from a controller or other hardware failure. I'm looking for definitive answers that can show *why* this is or isn't a good idea.

For clarity, I'm not talking about hardware or software RAID1, but simply creating two partitions and putting the same files on each. I have other methods for ensuring confidentiality and integrity, and I plan rotating the physical media every few years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an engineering perspective, all the partitions on a USB are on the same physical chip. In case the chip fails, you lose both. However, talking of bad sectors, then yes in case the bad sectors affect one partition, the other can still be accessed. For this, make sure the partitions are all primary and not logical. Logical partitions are software partitions and share the same physical space on the disk. Primary partitions are divided in the hardware. A fixed number of sectors are dedicated to a primary partition.

P.S. USBs are more reliable than optical media since the latter is vulnerable to scratches and breakages. I haven't personally known anyone who would store that important data on a USB. The best reliability is offered on the cloud.

Comment: Your note about primary vs. logical partitions is exactly the type of info I'm looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Given the price usb USB pendrives and that windows acts weird with removeable pendrives with multiple partitions I would advice to store on two different sticks.

That is if you want ot go this way, after all you wrote "the data is highly confidential".  Storing that on easy accesible removeable media is not a good way. At the very least you want to add encryptions somewhere. And a place to store the key.  And as always some off-site backups.

The latter is not a problem if your data is encrypted before sending it off-site. We are getting a bit off-track from your question though.